# Flutter test can't see content of expansion tile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am trying to test my code, and I've come across an issue where the flutter test is struggling to find the content under expansion tiles. 
The widget inspector does find the item ([widget inspector ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIFn6.png)) though, so I am slightly confused about the issue. 
This is my code for the expansion tile simplified

```
  ExpansionTile(
    key: Key('ExpansionTile'),
    initiallyExpanded: expand,
    title: TextFormField(
        readOnly: true,
        initialValue: name,
        ),
    children: [mainTable],
  )
```

This is my code for a simple table which my tester is trying to find

```
var mainTable = Table(
  key: Key('Table'),
  children: [],
);
```

Finally, this is my code for my test

```
testWidgets('Verify expansion tile has a table', (WidgetTester tester) async {
   await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp(appData));
   var finder = find.byKey(Key('ExpansionTile'));
   expect(finder, findsOneWidget); // works
   await tester.ensureVisible(finder);
   await tester.tap(finder);
   await tester.pumpAndSettle();
   expect(find.byKey(Key('Table')), findsOneWidget); // fails
 });
```

Comment: Try running the test as `flutter run  testfile_test.dart` instead of `flutter test testfile_test.dart`. This way you can visually see your test run. I'm assuming the `ExpansionTile` is not being expanded somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was solved after something I thought was originally unrelated. The expansion tile has the title showing through textformfield, which in my code had the property 'readOnly'. Issue there is that when the test found the tile by key, it may tap of the area of the tile which is also 'selectable', thus not expanding the tile. Thus, there are three solutions to the issue.

1. Change the TextFormField to Text
2. Change readOnly to enabled
3. Code the test to hit the expand button rather than anywhere on the key